# Expo React Native - Components switch places after building the apk / opening with QR code

Tags: components, react-native, expo

I am having trouble solving this issue.
I built a simple UI and I am trying to set inside a view two components
that one will take the left side and the other the right side.
I managed to make it work and it seems fine on the android emulator and on genymotion emulator
but when I use the expo qr code /build the apk the text and the inputs changes places:

Update:

I Tried a simpler code and the issue still happens:

[Image of changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyRcY.jpg)

```
<View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:"#fdf",alignItems:"center"}}>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',height:100,width:150,backgroundColor:"red"}}>
    <View style={{position:"absolute",left:0,width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
    <View style={{position:"absolute",right:0,width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
  </View>
</View>
```

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

Solved: the problem was the default rtl with react native
import {  I18nManager } from 'react-native';
I18nManager.allowRTL(false);